# send logs from multiple AWS lambda to s3

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a process which includes many lambdas that are called in sequence. Currently each lambda logs to its own cloudwatch log. I need a way to aggregate the logs from all the lambda's into one place (s3 or cloudwatch). I tried to change the name of the cloudwatch log in lambda's context but that did not work. Can anybody provide possible solutions

Comment: Take a look at [Exporting Log Data to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html) in the Amazon CloudWatch Logs User Guide.

Comment: that is just going to export different log files to s3, I need to aggregate the contents of the log file sorted by time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you'll have to create another Lambda function that uses those particular logs as Event Source.

You can find more information about it here: [Supported Event Sources -
 CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-cloudwatch-logs).